# New Docker Desktop credentials and preexisting Docker repository

Tags: docker

I have an old Docker hub account with this repository:

[image]

I just installed Docker Desktop, which asks for  credentials to connect to Docker hub, so I followed these instructions: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/get-started/#credentials-management-for-linux-users. I'm connected to the hub, the root repository I see has the same old name, but I don't see `arc` directory I created with my browser (see above):

[image]

Have I just created a new account and a parallel universe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This repository doesn't contain any image.
First push any image to this repository then you will be able to browse/view it in Docker-Desktop.

https://hub.docker.com/r/pauljurczak/arc

Comment: I'm "Connected to Hub" but pushing the image "pauljurczak/arc/docker-1" results in "requested access to the resource is denied".

Comment: tag your image like  - `docker tag pauljurczak/arc:docker-tag-1` and then `docker push pauljurczak/arc:docker-tag-1`

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be pushing, but Docker Hub is timing out. Maybe tomorrow it will be less busy.